# Undefined results for "web3.eth.accounts" in truffle console

Tags: web3js, truffle

truffle(development)> web3.eth.accounts[0]

gives output as "undefined"

truffle(development)> web3.eth.accounts

instead of showing all accounts details  gives the below output

```
Accounts {

currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],


_requestManager:

RequestManager {

 provider:

  HttpProvider {
    host: 'http://127.0.0.1:7545',

    httpAgent: [Agent],
    timeout: 0,

    headers: undefined,

    connected: true,

    send: [Function],

   ......blah...blah
```

but...

truffle(development)> web3.eth.getAccounts

is working. please help

Comment: If `web3.eth.getAccounts` is working, then why don't you simply use it??? As of web3.js v1, `web3.eth.accounts` is deprecated.

Comment: I can use it but I am not able to choose any of the accounts specifically which I was able to do with 'web3.eth.accounts[0]" , please let me know the replacement for this?

Comment: 1. You cannot use it, as it is `undefined`; you even specify it in your own question! 2. You've already found a replacement, and again - you even specify it in your own question!

Answer (score 17):

from @goodvibration in the comments :

> web3.eth.accounts is deprecated.

That is true. in the newer version of `web3.js` `web3.eth.getAccounts` returns a promise, so that is why doing :

```
var accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts();
accounts[0];
```

will return `undefined`.

**TLDR**: use this code instead

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(acc){ accounts = acc })
accounts[0]
```

Comment: I'm getting: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"

Comment: await is only valid in async function

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth-accounts.html doesn't say any deprecation. Can you point me a correct place to look at?

Answer (score 7):

Use the code below to retrieve all the accounts

```
   var accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

Use this code to reference a single account

```
   var account0;
   web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(result){
     account0 = result[0];
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

One line code: For displaying all accounts use:

`web3.eth.getAccounts()`

This works perfectly for displaying individual account addresses:
You can get the address of the account required by changing the index referenced by the result array in the fall back function

`web3.eth.getAccounts().then( function (result) { return result[0] });`

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that MetaMask and other dapp browsers will stop populating the injected Ethereum provider with user accounts by default.

To call getAccountS() you need to use await ethereum.enable() first. 
Consider this example

```
const ethereum = window.ethereum;
const web3 = window.web3;
const web3Instance = new Web3(ethereum);
const enabledWeb3 = await ethereum.enable();
const account = await web3Instance.eth.getAccounts();
const accountAddress = await account[0];
```

This is just an example of what you should be doing now after November 2018. The legacy code will not display the account.

Comment: This helped me when using React.  A pop-up appeared that said React wanted to connect to my account, and I clicked the button to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

`const web=new Web3(window.ethereum.CurrentProvider || "http://localhost:8545")`

Answer (score 0):

If `web3.eth.accounts` is not showing the expected result
then, follow these two simple step (Inside the truffle console)

1. `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(acc){ accounts = acc })`
2. `accounts`

That's is...
if you want specific account then `accounts[0/1/2...9]`

Answer (score 0):

All above solutions are correct with the fact that web3.eth.getAccounts() is returning a promise. But, Just make sure that you have to add `await window.ethereum.enable()` to actually connect your metamask wallet to the Dapp.

Because my code works after just adding it !!